# ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web.Config Issue

Tags: asp.net-core

My first stab at trying to implement an ASP.NET Core Application to Hosted IIS Server.

I believe I could a malformed XML `aspNetCore Attribute` of the web.config

```
<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
```

`%LAUNCHER_PATH%` is a placeholder.

based on [this information](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS)
I changed the `processPath="dotnet"` and `arguments=".\WebDevX1.dll"` however running with that produces 502.5 Error.  Running with just placeholders works fine.  It was my understanding that I need to change those placeholders in order to publish to the Hosted Server.

Whether I modify the placeholders in those 2 attributes or not, the web.config `aspNetCore Attribute` still shows an error
[image]

When I run locally from Visual Studio, the web.config reverts back to the placeholders:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"
```

ASP.NET Core 1.0.0 is installed locally
[image]

And my Host indicates they support .NET Core defaultly.

If someone has any insight as to what I'm missing I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You referencing post more than half year ago - asp.net core changed a lot. Why you think you should change something from default `web.config`? Just publish your app - and file will be changed automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the publish-iis tool configured to run as a post-publish script. This tool replaces LAUNCHER_PATH and LAUNCHER_ARGS. You can find more details about this in my post about [running ASP.Net Core applications with IIS](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/).

After project.json to .csproj transition the publish-iis tool was converted to an MSBuild task (the [TransformWebConfig](https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/blob/ccddbc285caff89dd5cbe550dfb424ea0e293b4f/src/Publish/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks/Tasks/TransformWebConfig.cs) task)

Comment: I noticed Controllers Folder is missing, as well as, bundleconfig.json, package.json, program.cs, startup.cs,,, what do I need to modify to include those files?

Comment: Why do you need these? Especially *.cs files? You published a compiled application and not sources.

Comment: I need the sources because it's easier for other people to simply download the application from that development site.

Comment: My other question is, whenever we make changes, does this have to be published every time?  Not FTP'd ?

Comment: Publishing means gathering all the build outputs, dependencies and runtime and putting it to a folder to make it runnable. If you change your code you need to rebuild your application which results in changing the outputs so yes - you need to re-publish. Then you just copy the published application to the target server.

Comment: I'm accustomed to prior to ASP.NET Core when you just FTP'd the application and all of the files were available in the project directory.